# How do I profile all database activity in a Java Spring/Hibernate application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, aspectj

I would like to record (almost) all database activity for HTTP requests in a Spring/Hibernate web application using an `@Aspect` and `HandlerInterceptor`.

Ideally, I could wrap the `@Aspect` `@Around` calls to `java.sql.Statement.execute`, but since that class is Java and may not use the same class loader, I have to settle for second best.

I have an `@Aspect` working for calls to JdbcTemplate using the `execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))` pointcut as explained [here](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/profile-sql-statements-in-java-spring/), but I also need any database activity invoked by Hibernate.

Does anybody have advice on this? I'm up for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. Its usage from within Spring applications is well documented. You would have then full AOP power, e.g. you can use `call()` pointcuts and many more instead of only `execution()`, apply your aspects to classes which are not Spring Beans and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure what more to do than having `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` in my Spring configuration to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, though. All of the annotations I'm using are also in the `org.aspectj.lang.annotation` package.

Comment: Even the exception being thrown comes from AspectJ: `org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'sqlOperation(sql)' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'call'`... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing that the autoproxy setting is for Spring AOP. AspectJ does not use any proxies. Check out Spring documentation, chapter [9.8 Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). If you do not use real AspectJ you cannot use `call()` pointcuts.

Comment: If things weren't so complicated to set up compile-time weaving, I think this would have been the way I went. It provides the flexibility I need, but I don't think it's worth the effort to set up compile-time weaving in my development environment using Eclipse and Gradle. I'll mark this correct because it probably would have been the solution had I pursued it further. Thanks!

Comment: If you read the chapter I pointed you to, you will find that it describes LTW (load time weaving), not CTW (compile time weaving). ;-) And BTW, it is not so compilcated to set up either CTW or LTW with Maven. I cannot say anything about Gradle though, I am a Maven guy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you actually want to profile all the database operations, that are being performed, A simplistic approach would be to go for logging them. Instead of using AOP,i rather suggest you to use a offshelf TPL known as Log4JDBC.

Basically, all you must do is replace your datasource declaration with something like this :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="net.sf.log4jdbc.Log4jdbcProxyDataSource" >
```

Once this is done, you just need to setup your loggers to log relative log messages. The various loggers available with log4Jdbc are

```
jdbc.sqlonly: Logs only SQL
jdbc.sqltiming: Logs the SQL, post-execution, including timing execution statistics
jdbc.audit: Logs ALL JDBC calls except for ResultSets
jdbc.resultset: all calls to ResultSet objects are logged
jdbc.connection: Logs connection open and close events
```

For e.g. :

```
<logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" additivity ="false">             
     <level value="info" />                
 </logger>  
 <logger name="jdbc.resultset" additivity ="false">              
     <level value="error" />        
 </logger>  
 <logger name="jdbc.audit" additivity ="false">
     <level value="error" />        
 </logger>   
 <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" additivity ="false">              
     <level value="error" />        
 </logger>   
 <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" additivity ="false">           
     <level value="error" />       
 </logger>           
 <logger name="jdbc.connection" additivity ="false">              
     <level value="error" />        
 </logger>  
 <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" additivity ="false">            
     <level value="error" />        
 </logger>
```

More details can be found at the [Log4JDBC official Site](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/).

You can find the hibernate specific setup [here](http://blog.jhades.org/logging-the-actualreal-sql-queries-of-a-springhibernate-application/).

I have successfully implemented it in an application using JdbcTemplate.

Comment: Looks like a neat library. For my solution, though, I'd like to keep a running tally of times per HTTP request. I'm not convinced that a simple logging library would be able to accomplish that. +1 for the suggestion, though!